# Rails save active record form through the associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have these models in my Rails app. My use-case is multilingual data. First I want to store the default language version, then it will be possible to add other language data.

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_versions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category_versions, allow_destroy: true
end

class CategoriesVersion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :categories
  has_many :categories_contents
  has_one :langs
end


class CategoriesContent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :categories_versions
end
```

And I would like to save the record with one toplevel record with associated record in `CategoriesVersion` and `CategoriesContent`.

Using data from params and generated inside `create` method in the controller.

I got first and second table, but I don't know how to add attributes for third table, nested in second one, if it is possible. So the association from CategoriesVersion to CategoriesContent

```
     category_data = { category: {
      kind: "user",
      featured_image: "test",
      featured_image_title: "test",
      editorial_id: nil,
        category_versions_attributes: [
          {lang_id: Lang.find_by_lang("francais").id},
          {published: false},
          {featured: false} #data["featured"] || false
        ]
    }}


test = Category.create(category_data["category"])
```

Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue, I think [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) is the configuration that you need in your models to save the nested data just saving the category.

Comment: Thanks! This is it! I will test it to write over 3 tables, thank you

Comment: I am trying to get it work, I will update comment by my new settings